# Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, desktop, platform

I know there's JScript.NET, but it isn't the same as the JavaScript we know from the web.

Does anyone know if there are any JavaScript based platforms/compilers for desktop development? Most specifically Windows desktop development.

Comment: I did this back then: [link](http://alinacierdem.com/standalone-javascript-application-with-chromium/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Windows 8 allows for Windows Store Apps to be written in HTML5/JavaScript.

Comment: +1: windows 8 is pretty cool!

Comment: That reminds me of node-webkit (a similar framework for node.js): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140/is-it-possible-to-create-desktop-applications-with-node-js

Answer (score 26):

There is [XULRunner](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner), which let's you build GUI apps like Firefox using JavaScript and XUL. It has a lot of extension to JavaScript though, using XPCOM. They also offer [Prism](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Prism) which let's you build web apps that work offline, sort of like AIR. Yahoo uses it for their [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) email desktop client.

Comment: Instead of Prism you could use Google Chrome and then you could use the built in Google Gears support for offline storage.

Comment: I was so excited to find XULRunner a couple of years ago, but then found out that it doesn't support any of the abilities firefox has for DOM manipulation and other stuff I'd expected to get (I don't remember what else it didn't have, maybe AJAX?)

Answer (score 25):

Yes, with [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/). Adobe AIR lets you make desktop applications with Javascript, Flex, or Flash.

Answer (score 25):

Looks like there are 3 types of html5-desktop app

SDK

- https://qt-project.org/
- http://awesomium.com
- http://berkelium.org
- http://www.appcelerator.com/platform

Browser runtime

- http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner
- http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Node.js based

- http://appjs.com/
- https://github.com/maccman/bowline

Comment: Add electronjs to Node.js based

Answer (score 9):

"[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js. You can write native apps in HTML and Javascript with node-webkit. It also lets you call Node.js modules directly from the DOM..."

Comment: Node-webkit looks really interesting: it allows you to access node.js libraries directly from a web browser, all in one .html file.

Answer (score 8):

There's [Titanium Developer](http://www.appcelerator.com/) which is similar to Adobe AIR (html+css+javascript), but does not require a framework to be pre-installed.

Comment: [The Future of Titanium Desktop](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/01/the-future-of-titanium-desktop.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can make a desktop application using XML and javascript (and/or VBS) using the Windows Script host.

The trick is to save your XML file with a `.hta` extension. [See this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx).

Comment: I forgot about this, I'll have to try it out a little bit more. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if it could be compiled too.

Comment: true... maybe under .NET? I haven't tried it tho as I stopped using windows way back, but it may be worth looking up

Comment: can't find anything like it in MSDN. Then again, I probably didn't look hard enough

Answer (score 6):

There's [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/), a JavaScript engine written in C and [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), an implementation of JavaScript in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Try [AppJS](http://appjs.com/), It is an SDK on top of NodeJS and Chromium Embedded Framework. You can build desktop apps easily with the web technologies.

- Webpage: http://appjs.com
- Github: https://github.com/appjs

Comment: AppJS is Deprecated

Answer (score 3):

[Google Gears](http://gears.google.com). There's also Mozilla's [XUL](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/xul/), but it's too bit complicated, IMHO (albeit extremely powerful).

Comment: It appears that Google Gears is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a new interesting technology going on. It's in a quite early stage but works good already. It's called Packaged Apps and is using Chrome as a runtime and works on both Pc and Mac. Have a look at http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Comment: This looks very similar to node-webkit (which allows node.js libraries to be used in HTML documents, just like browser-side Javascript.)

Comment: Yes Node-Webkit looks very promising. Started looking in to it some days ago. Have a look: [link](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)

Comment: I'm familiar with node-webkit already, but does "Packaged Apps" allow node.js functions to be used in the HTML DOM (like node-webkit?)

Comment: No it doesn't as far as I know. I found this project on Github but it's not much there yet. [link](https://github.com/arunoda/chrome-node). This might be something too, haven't checked yet. [link](http://nodejs.davidherron.com/2012/10/chrome-apps-office-hours-nodejs-in.html)

Comment: See also my answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490825/save-without-prompt-in-a-chrome-packaged-app/13623999#13623999)

Comment: It is not recommended to use Chrome packaged apps anymore -- see http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Answer (score 2):

Another option I didn't see mentioned is for Cocoa (Mac OS X, iPhone OS) applications you can use a web view (embedded WebKit) as the application UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [JavaLikeScript](http://javalikescript.free.fr/), it does not provide the same native/root objects that a web browser but it has network and user interface features.

Answer (score 2):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), originally Atom Shell, allows applications to be written in web technologies (HTML, JS, CSS) and run on any of the major operating systems, including Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Yahoo's Konfabulator](http://widgets.yahoo.com/tools/) for the windows desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Script# has extensions for Vista Gadgets.

http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some JSOS (Javascript Operating Systems), sort-of still need a browser.

http://fractalbrain.net/ /* The Best. */

http://cometdesktop.com/ /* Alright. */

http://skylightproject.com/ /* Worst */

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sort-of still need a browser"?

Answer (score 0):

I answered with node-webkit above, but I recently saw a presentation on [**Tint2**](https://www.trueinteractions.com/tint2/docs/).  It seems to address security concerns with node-webkit and looks promising.