# Desktop application on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, desktop-application

Is there any system/compiler/SDK/IDE that provides an ability to develop desktop applications using JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript desktop applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780916/javascript-desktop-applications)

Comment: no, I don't want to use .NET libraries

Comment: You need some framework after all, .Net, Adobe AIR, Mozilla XUL etc. Since you're "DotNet Ninja", I thought you're interested in .Net :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)**.

It uses webkit to render the webpage and execute the Javascript, and you will have access to all the Node.js javascript API (reading/writing files, …)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Appcelerator(http://www.appcelerator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You might try [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) or maybe [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an .net application for execute javascript codes.

You can make this:

```
string CompilerJScript (string JSource) {
            return Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(JSource, Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
}
```

You need to reference the `Microsoft.JScript` dll assembly.

**Note:** 
*don't using only keyword to reference the assembly. right click on
   the project in VS and choose 'Add reference'*

Comment: Give more information, please

Answer (score 1):

There is the [jls](http://javalikescript.free.fr/) JavaScript platform and eclipse WTP as IDE.

Jls supports graphical user interface, file system manipulation, unit testing, thread, process, network sockets and selectors, HTTP client and server, SQL, image manipulation, zip file...

You can found the desktop documentation [here](http://javalikescript.free.fr/jsdoc/sa/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AppJs](http://appjs.org/)

Build Desktop Applications  for Linux, Windows and Mac using HTML, CSS and Javascript. I'm planning to use it too.