# What is the most normal way to deliver a ClojureScript desktop application

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I have a desktop application written in Clojure that suffers greatly from JVM startup time and is a really good fit for ClojureScript. It is delivered as a jar file for the JVM, what is the equivalent for ClojureScript/JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deployment rules for regular javascript apply. There's nothing wrong with just sending the user the optimized .js file emitted from clojurescript's compiler. Usually this means double clicking the script or running from command line as if it were python or ruby.

[Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript)

For windows machines, you have Windows Script House http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx

If you run a *nix you can use Node.js http://nodejs.org/
Note: You may need to lookup tips for getting google's closure library to work with node.js via https://github.com/hsch/node-goog if you will depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this? https://github.com/maccman/macgap