# Can I make a local Standalone JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web-applications, local

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript)

I am very familiar with web-based JavaScript as it relates to html and canvas, but I was wondering if it would be possible to make a complete standalone application using javascript that would NOT open in a browser.  Is there any GUI or command prompt that would allow me to do this?

If not, I might be open to writing some other program that could read html, as Notch did with the Minecraft login screen.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but Node.js might be it.

http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Along with that, a quick Google search gives [Topcube](https://github.com/creationix/topcube) as a possible GUI library for Node, although, interestingly, it looks like it's basically creating a GTK window that communicates with the Node server.

Answer (score 5):

There are frameworks and libraries that are designed for this. Here are a few:

- [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/) - a platform that uses the web technologies (HTML, Javascript, CSS) to create cross platform (*really* cross platform) applications. Looks **very** nice, although I haven't used it.
- [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) - uses HTML and ActionScript/JavaScript to build native applications, although they've dropped support for Linux. :(

Answer (score 2):

There's also Rhino and Swing on the JVM.

Comment: A downvote here makes no sense; it's another option.