# Alternative for build desktop app with HTML, CSS, & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, desktop-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript)

There are alternatives tool for build desktop app with HTML, CSS, and JS? Since Mozilla's Chromeless Browser have stopped from development, and Titanium's new version have focused only to Mobile App. Do you know what is tool that which have similar function like Chromeless/Titanium?

Comment: Did you check Adobe Air technology?

Comment: There's [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner), and you could also use JScript in Visual Studios, which is more or less JS.

Comment: @pierre oh.. I never use that..

Comment: @JaredFarrish I never learned Visual Studios.. I must complete my project as soon as possible. I don't have many time for learn it from start..

Comment: So in other words, you need to create an application and you only know HTML, CSS and JS in a web environment? I have no idea what you're needing to do, but it could be tricky. You could also build a Chrome extension, package it with a [Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) for which you've configured it to run, and give that a shot.

Comment: I heard about [AppJS](http://appjs.org/) a few days ago, haven't tried it

Comment: @wong2 oh. I ever heard about that. But, it's likely still beta..

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) should be the one for you. It creates a desktop app which is basically a webkit wrapper. Then with that, you can build your app straight in HTML, CSS, JS or even Flash. It has a few set of JS API which you could learn for native operations like file access and more.

Recent versions of AIR prepackage the runtime with the app, which makes your app stand-alone and will not need the AIR platform installed on the target client.

For easy development, [Aptana Studio 2](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) has a plugin that helps you in developing AIR apps and automates much of your AIR app building like package compiling, app previewing etc. It's quite outdated though (AIR 1.5 and AIR 2 beta) and you might want to update the SDK. Also you could Google around on how to tweak the compiler options to build a stand-alone app.

Comment: I'm sorry I've try Adobe AIR.. And my web app is run so slower than app that I've build with chromeless. Every element that have -webkit-animate run so slow. And video flash player that I'm embedded is play slow when I try to scroll the page.