# Can I Use Dojo Toolkit For Desktop App Development

Tags: javascript, dojo, toolkit

I Want To Ask basic question of dojo toolkit usage 
Can i use it for desktop application development these applications run on windows platform may or may not have internet connectivity
If So Than How
Kindly Answer In Detail
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Dojo is javascript framework/component collection. So your question could be answered here:

[Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript)

Adobe Air won the race in this question.

Answer (score 1):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) article;

> Dojo Toolkit is an open source modular JavaScript library (or more
>   specifically JavaScript toolkit) designed to ease the rapid
>   development of cross-platform, JavaScript/Ajax-based applications and
>   web sites.

That means there is no way to use desktop app development **but** again in Wikipedia;

> Dojo can be used in JavaScript-based Adobe AIR applications. It has
>   been modified to meet AIR's security requirements.
>
> Sitepen, a Dojo consulting company, has made an Adobe AIR application
>   called "Dojo Toolbox" using Dojo. It includes an API viewer, and a GUI
>   to Dojo's build system. Normally, the build system is run from within
>   Rhino, but in this AIR application the build system can be run from
>   AIR, without use of java.

So when we look [Adebe Air Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime);

> Adobe Integrated Runtime, also known as Adobe AIR, is a cross-platform
>   runtime environment developed by Adobe Systems for building Rich
>   Internet Applications (RIA) using Adobe Flash, Adobe Flex, HTML, and
>   Ajax, that can be run as **desktop applications** or on mobile devices.

So, YES.

Answer (score 1):

This depends somewhat on what you mean by "desktop application".

If the app can be implemented as a self-hosting web app, e.g., local DB for storage, run an embedded server, etc. then sure–it's just a web app, coincidentally hosted on the same machine.

You *could* run it in an Air app, but why not just use Air then?

Comment: Yes My App Contain DB Access And Runs On Windows OS Not Servers
My main purpose of using javascript and HTML CSS is Specifically For UI the code will is preferably be in c++ Or C# If Adobe Flex Or Flash Give Me The Same Power As C++ Or C# I Will Preferrably use It 
Kindly Tell Me Will Air Do All This For Me 
Explain Please I AM Not getting You Also Recommendations Of SDK for Air Development

Comment: @user1366440 I wouldn't bother doing desktop UI work with JS/CSS/Dojo etc. As I said, you could embed a web server, run it locally, and just connect to it--that may or may not suit your application's needs. If it's Windows only, I'd just build it up using .NET and the VS UI designer--why do anything else?

Comment: I Heard About Appcelerator TITANIUM Any Idea About it

Comment: @user1366440 AFAIK that's a mobile plaform, but I've never used it, so can't help--sorry!