# Chrome fileSystem save without prompt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I am trying to create two buttons `save` and `save as` which I have my save as function for the most part set.

```
readwrite({type:"saveFile",suggestedName:fileName},function(writeFileEntry){
    writeFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer){
        writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
            console.log("Saved");
        };
        writer.write(new Blob([current.getValue()],{type:type}));
    },log);
});
```

for sake of keeping this minimal **know that all variables are assigned**

But I can't seem to get a save function to work nor read any other documentation to just save the present file without asking for a filename. I know I should truncate the memory in the saved file if I write less than the original file size:

```
writer.onwrite = function() {
    writer.onwrite = null;
    writer.truncate(writer.position);
};
```

But I can't get anywhere now I have a `displayPath` which gives me almost close to a full destination.

Does anyone know where I can read on this or can give me an example of how to save without the prompt, basically save the file with the same name and in the same location.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490825/save-without-prompt-in-a-chrome-packaged-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894660/chrome-filesystem-save-file-without-prompt-location

Comment: Both answers are incorrect and I've found the solution myself I'll post the correct answer soon