# Is there any way to use javascript for stand-alone desktop applications

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use JavaScript for stand-alone desktop applications, I mean without any browser interaction.

Comment: Are you asking something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript ?

Comment: check out [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)