# Making Widgets using CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: html, css, windows, web-widget

I really admire the power of HTML5+CSS3 combo and I know that a browser is needed to run them(pretty obvious).

But I was wondering that is there any way that I can make  Desktop Widgets/Apps (like a clock or weather app) using HTML5 and CSS3(Javascript for logic)?

(I know that for mobiles, phonegap is the solution but what for desktop?)

Comment: For Windows desktop application you will need to resort to C#, C++, Java, VB or .net

Comment: otherwise check developing apps for Windows 8

Comment: @acudars :I know the languages for windows,but sorry ,the question was about the possibility of using HTML and CSS for this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: http://www.tidesdk.org/

It allows you to create multi-platform desktop apps with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript